# After Login Show me from which city and country user is using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Here is my table....

```
 UserID     FullName   City    Country       Usr     Pswrd
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 101         MRJONE    LHR       PAK         ABC       123
```

On form1 I have

```
SQLCon = New SqlConnection(sqldata)
    SQLCon.Open()
    Dim qry As String = "select usr,pswrd from tbllogin where usr= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and pswrd='" & TextBox11.Text & "'"
    SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(qry, SQLCon)
    SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

    If SQLdr.HasRows Then
        Main.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid User")
    End If
    Me.Hide()
```

On Form2 I have some labels and and Textboxes

```
labelFullName.text  = 
citytextbox.text = 
Countrytextbox.text =
```

How can i fill these...

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**

Comment: Then whats the better idea for this Sir?

Comment: Use systempassword is true.....

Comment: `select usr,pswrd,Country from...`  really, really hard stuff.  Do not concat strings to make SQL, use paramters and never store passwords as plaintext - hash them (I know you have already heard that...but it is that important)

Comment: Thanks Sir. I got it. But still waiting for my answer.

Comment: I already gave it to you - read the part marked as code!

Comment: But i did not understand. I want when i logged with any user His details should be showed in labels and textboxs as well. This is what i want.

Comment: `select usr,pswrd,City,Country from...` then read the values you want from the `reader` and put then in labels and textboxes as well.  You have to do some of the work yourself

Comment: Sir im not getting you please write the whole Sub once.

Comment: Dear Sir Please guide me. still waiting... i tried but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.....

```
 Public Sub GetdataName()
    Try
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT FullName, Contact, Designation, Division, District, Center, Permission, Usr FROM dbo.TblLogin Where Usr='" & Login.UserTextBox.Text & "'", SQLCon)
        SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        While (SQLdr.Read() = True)
            TSSLUser.Text = SQLdr(7)
            TSSLDesignation.Text = SQLdr(2)
            TSSLDivision.Text = SQLdr(3)
            TSSLDistrict.Text = SQLdr(4)
            TSSLCenter.Text = SQLdr(5)
        End While
        SQLCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```